# Wrong pen color

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi

I try to change pen color with this code :

```
redPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID,1,0xFF0000); 
SelectObject(hdc, redPen);
```

but it change from black into blue. And no matter what color is, because pen always will be blue if i try to set new color or black if i do nothing.
Here is whole code:

```
#include "windows.h"

int N=50;
int M=30;
int X=25;

int width=X * N;
int height=X * M;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE h,HINSTANCE hprevinstance,LPSTR lpcmdline,int ncmdshow){
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;

    ZeroMemory(&msg,sizeof(MSG));
    wc.cbSize=sizeof(wc);
    wc.style=CS_OWNDC|CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc=WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra=0;
    wc.cbWndExtra=0;
    wc.hInstance=h;
    wc.hIcon=LoadIcon(NULL,IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor=LoadCursor(h,IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground=(HBRUSH)GetStockObject(GRAY_BRUSH);
    wc.lpszMenuName=NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName="main";
    wc.hIconSm=LoadIcon(NULL,IDI_APPLICATION);
    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) return 0;

    if(!(hwnd=CreateWindowEx(NULL,"main","test",WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW|WS_VISIBLE,0,0,width,height,NULL,NULL,h,NULL))) return 0;

    ShowWindow(hwnd,SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while(msg.message != WM_QUIT){
        if(PeekMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0,PM_REMOVE)){
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
      HDC hdc;
      PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HPEN redPen;
    switch (message){
    case WM_PAINT:
      hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
      redPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID,1,0xFF0000); 
      SelectObject(hdc, redPen);
      for(int i=0;i<width;i+=X){
        MoveToEx(hdc,i,0,NULL);
        LineTo(hdc,i,height);
      }
      for(int j=0;j<height;j+=X){
        MoveToEx(hdc,0,j,NULL);
        LineTo(hdc,width,j);
      }
      EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
      return 0;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Sorry to say it, but it really is a case of [RTFM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183449(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
  redPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID,1,0xFF0000);
```

No, that's definitely the wrong identifier name, it should be "bluePen".  COLORREF is encoded as 0x00bbggrr in hex.  So 0x00ff0000 is blue, not red.

Fall in the pit of success by using the RGB macro instead:

```
  redPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(0xFF, 0, 0));
```